# Видимость private константы атрибутом

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, const, атрибуты

Пусть есть класс

```
class Class
{
}
```

и атрибут

```
class SomePropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SomePropertyAttribute(string prop)
    {
    }
}
```

Почему компилятор не выдаёт ошибку, если применить атрибут к классу следующим образом

```
[SomeProperty(Weird)] //<-- Weird const use
class Class
{
    private const string Weird = nameof(Weird);
}
```

?

Ведь в данном случае приватная константа используется за пределами фигурных скобок, определяющих класс. Тогда как документация (см. [private](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/private)) гласит:

> Ключевое слово *private* является модификатором доступа к члену.
>   ...
>   Доступ к закрытым членам можно получить **только внутри тела**
>   класса или структуры, в которой они объявлены ...

Comment: этот случай похож на У меня есть `public string prop_x{ get { return Weird;} }` Но ведь Weird защищён `private`. Есть механизмы позволяющие увидеть приватные поля снаружи. И атрибут - один из. Он то даёт ссылку на приватное поле, а не само поле.

Comment: @nick_n_a, на мой взгляд - не совсем похож. Я понял, что имелось ввиду, но вы скорее про _run-time_ доступность, тогда как вопрос про _compile-time_ доступность. С этой точки зрения, в случае со свойством всё логично - `prop_x`, являясь членом класса, законно имеет доступ к `Weird`.

Comment: Атрибуты считаются частью класса-структуры (не смотря на то что  находятся за фигурными скобками). Т.е. описание класса начинается не с слова класс, а с первого атрибута который к нему относится ели они есть (A class_declaration consists of an optional set of attributes). Почитать про это можно тут https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes  Да, я зачем-то описал "runtime" доступность.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Как ни странно, ваш пример не противоречит спецификации языка.

Я не смог сам найти и правильно проинтерпретировать нужную цитату из стандарта, но мне помог [аналогичный вопрос](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/20186) в гитхаб-репозитории компилятора. Как оказалось, *разрешение имён (name resolution) для атрибутов класса проходит в контексте самого класса*. Поэтому, кстати, вы можете ссылаться на константу просто как `Weird`, а не `Class.Weird`. «Нарушения» правил видимости тут не происходит, атрибут как бы находится внутри класса. Давайте найдём подтверждение этого в спецификации.

На этапе разрешения имён, `Weird` классифицируется как «простое имя» (simple name), и его привязка регулируется [разделом 7.6.2 спецификации](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#simple-names). Релевантная часть:

> - If `K` is zero and the *simple_name* appears within a *block* ... [не подходит — VladD]
> - If `K` is zero and the *simple_name* appears within the body of a generic method declaration ... [не подходит — VladD]
> - Otherwise, for each instance type `T` ([The instance type](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#the-instance-type)), starting with the instance type of the immediately enclosing type declaration and continuing with the instance type of each enclosing class or struct declaration (if any):

---

Лирическо-бюрократическое отступление.

Подходит ли нам эта часть? Лежит ли атрибут вообще в какой либо декларации типа (immediately enclosing type declaration)? Кажется, что он лежит снаружи, но это не так. Согласно [разделу 10.1](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/classes.md#class-declarations), декларация класса является декларацией типа

> A *class_declaration* is a *type_declaration*

и **включает в себя** объявление атрибутов:

> A *class_declaration* consists of an optional set of attributes ([Attributes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/attributes.md#attributes)), followed by...

---

Возвращаемся к теме. У нас `T` есть тип `Class`. В спецификации есть следующие подпункты:

> - If `K` is zero and the declaration of `T` includes a type parameter with name `I` ... [не подходит, у нас нет параметров-типов — VladD]
> - Otherwise, if a member lookup ([Member lookup](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#member-lookup)) of `I` in `T` with `K` type arguments produces a match

Эта часть подходит, т. к. `Weird` является константой-членом класса (в чём можно убедиться, пролистав раздел [Member lookup](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/expressions.md#member-lookup)).

Итак, в этом случае `Weird` разрешается как часть типа `Class`.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Т.е., если резюмировать, атрибут является частью класса, и на самом деле он не `[A] class C { }`, а как бы `class C { [A] }`, о чём и говорится в спецификации, и в подтверждение чему IL-код в соседнем ответе, а кажущаяся незаконность ситуации имеет место из-за синтаксиса (на мой взгляд, несколько нелогичного в данном случае).

Comment: @i-one: Именно так. Да, синтаксис немного нелогичен, правда.

Answer (score 7):

Атрибуты в C# добавляют метаданные на сборку. Если точнее - и на наш класс.

В этой ситуации область видимости атрибута и константы совпадают на уровне компиляции. Поэтому ваш пример работает.

```
TypeDef #2 (02000003)
-------------------------------------------------------
    TypDefName: XmlParsing.Class  (02000003)
    Flags     : [NotPublic] [AutoLayout] [Class] [AnsiClass] [BeforeFieldInit]  (00100000)
    Extends   : 01000011 [TypeRef] System.Object
    Field #1 (04000001)
    -------------------------------------------------------
        Field Name: Weird (04000001)
        Flags     : [Private] [Static] [Literal] [HasDefault]  (00008051)
    DefltValue: (String) We
        CallCnvntn: [FIELD]
        Field type:  String
        Signature : 06 0e 

    Method #1 (06000002) 
    -------------------------------------------------------
        MethodName: .ctor (06000002)
        Flags     : [Public] [HideBySig] [ReuseSlot] [SpecialName] [RTSpecialName] [.ctor]  (00001886)
        RVA       : 0x0000205a
        ImplFlags : [IL] [Managed]  (00000000)
        CallCnvntn: [DEFAULT]
        hasThis 
        ReturnType: Void
        No arguments.
        Signature : 20 00 01 

    CustomAttribute #1 (0c00000f)
    -------------------------------------------------------
        CustomAttribute Type: 06000001
        CustomAttributeName: XmlParsing.SomePropertyAttribute :: instance void .ctor(class System.String)
        Length: 10
        Value : 01 00 05 57 65 69 72 64  00 00                   >   Weird        <
        ctor args: ("Weird")
```